# Clean permutation composition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What is a clean way to compose two permutations given as integer lists in Haskell?

I know  `A !! i` is the infix array access operator like the C++ equivalent `A[i]`, but I am stuck as to how to map it. In C++ you would loop over i letting `C[i] = A[B[i]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you choose instead to store them in `Data.Vector` or `Data.Vector.Unboxed` from the `vector` package, you can use the [`backpermute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v%3abackpermute)  combinator directly.

Then what you want is just `backpermute a b`, and your permutations can be stored unboxed and packed together in memory, reducing your memory footprint as well.

Comment: Thanks Ed, unsafeBackpermute it is. Nice, seems to work on transformations too. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell equivalent of that loop in C++ would be something like this:

```
c = map (a !!) b
```

So you could say

```
compose = map . (!!)
```

and write

```
c = compose a b
```

But `!!` is for lists, not arrays, and indexing is not particularly efficient. You may want to consider using a [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector).